# APCI Error while installing

Tags: dual-boot

I could not install Ubuntu, as it showed following

```
APCI Error: No handler for region
APCI Error: Region Embedded control
APCI Error: Method parse/execution failed
No caching mode page found
Assuming drive cache:write through

(initramfs) mount:  mounting/dev/loop0//filesystem.squashfs failed: input/output error
```

Comment: Do you mean ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface)?

Comment: I think this ^ is the answer here

Answer (score 1):

"input/output error" looks like the installation medium is broken. Please try again with a different DVD or USB drive.

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!

Answer (score 1):

Those specific ACPI errors won't affect the installation, they are warnings from the Advanced Configuration and Power Interface driver concerning some issues in the ACPI tables in your machine and won't cause the problem you are seeing.  It is worth sanity checking your installation media, there is an option in the early install boot menu to check the installation media.